# NullPointerException on android 4.4.3 but not 4.1.2

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a problem where by a section of my android app works fine on android version 4.1.2 but throws a NullPointerException when the same section is executed on android 4.4.3. My minimum sdk is set to 15 and target sdk is 21. Please find the code below:

```
try {
    FileInputStream towe = new FileInputStream(path2);
    re = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(towe));
    while ((res = re.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(res);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        re.close();           //ERROR IS GENERATED AT THIS LINE
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Morning guys, been away for a while. It turned out Exception was being thrown because of file path. I had hard-coded the path for android 4.1.2 but in 4.4.3 that path was different even though device was the same. I ended up using the

a*ndroid.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();*

method. Now working fine on both. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Does `path2` refer to a valid path in both environments?

Comment: This will occur if `new FileInputStream(path2)` throws an exception, as `re` has not been initialized at the point you are trying to `close()` it.

Comment: can you post you logcat

Comment: Try [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). No need to close it manually.

Comment: Does path contains external sd? There are more restrictions on Android 4.4

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way to write this, from a number of perspectives:

```
 try (FileInputStream towe = new FileInputStream(path2);
      Reader re = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(towe))) {
    while ((res = re.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(res);
    }
 }
```

1. Use *try-with-resources*.  It is simpler, and more concise.
2. Don't catch an exception, and continue as if nothing happened.  If you find yourself doing this, you are *probably* catching the exception in the wrong place.
3. Printing stacktraces in random places is a bad idea.

If you don't use *try-with-resources* then you need to test that `re` is non-null in the `finally` block to avoid the NPE.  It would look like this with the erroneous stacktraces and exception squashing removed.

```
 try {
    FileInputStream towe = new FileInputStream(path2);
    re = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(towe));
    while ((res = re.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(res);
    }
 } finally {
     if (re != null) {
        re.close();
     }
 }
```

And even then, there is a theoretical risk that `towe` won't be closed.  (Hint: `Error` subclasses.)

---

> NullPointerException on android 4.4.3 but not 4.1.2

What that most likely means is that `new FileInputStream(path2);` is throwing an exception (probably an `IOException` of some kind) on one platform and not the other.  The clue is most likely in the I/O exception's message.

Comment: Agreed, butn ot helpful for the problem, though.

Comment: Morning guys, been away for a while. It turned out Exception was being thrown because of file path. I hard-coded the path for android 4.1.2 but in 4.4.3 that path was different even though device was the same. I ended using the android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();